# Is rename refactoring working for somebody in strongly typed razor views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor, refactoring, strongly-typed-view

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
     public string PostalCode {get;set;}
}
```

Then I have a razor view

```
@model MvcApp1.Person

Your location is: @Model.PostalCode
```

When I am using Visual Studio's 2010 rename refactoring (Ctrl+R,R) the property gets renamed on the model class, but stays the same in the view.

My understanding is that since the view is strongly typed, renaming should have also happened in the view.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On a related note, the views support IntelliSense, but they are not compiled. There is nothing to enforce the 'strongly typed' nature of the views other than some fancy highlighting.

Comment: as iaimtomisbehave pointed out, there is a way to enable compilation of the views: <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>, but it would be great to see refactorings working too..

Comment: @OlegD. - this should really be in the accepted answer I think... I almost glossed over it but it gets 90% of the way there (assurance, at least)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

VS's refactoring engine doesn't support Razor.

Comment: how about compile time checking for the view? since after refactoring there is no PostalCode property, is there a way to get a compiler error?

Comment: @Oleg Yes in your project file change <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews> to  <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>

Comment: Show your support for the feature here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2372233-support-refactoring-in-razor-views

Comment: Still not support in visual studio 2015, but resharper supports it